# Firebase admin sdk unable to decode jwt token

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt, google-cloud-functions

I have written api in node using express and hosted it on firebase functions. I am trying to secure the api using firebase authentication.

After the user has logged into my android application using Google authentication, I am getting the firebase jwt token and using it in  Authorisation header. But I am getting 403 unauthorized. When I checked the firebase function log there I am seeing the error

```
Error while verifying Firebase ID token: { Error: Decoding Firebase ID token failed. Make sure you passed the entire string JWT which represents an ID token. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens for details on how to retrieve an ID token.
at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
at FirebaseAuthError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/srv/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
```

Code for getting firebase jwt token

```
 private fun updateUI(user: FirebaseUser) {
    user.getIdToken(false)
        .addOnCompleteListener {
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                val token = it.result!!.token
                if (token != null) {
                    Timber.d("token: $token")
                    sharePref.put("token", token)
                    presenter.getData(1)
                }
            }
        }
    val header = navView.getHeaderView(0)
    header.user_name.text = user.displayName
    header.user_email.text = user.email
    picasso.load(user.photoUrl).into(header.imageView)
}
```

Code for firebase admin sdk token verification

```
var validateFirebaseIdToken = async function (req, res, next) {
    if (!req.headers.authorization || !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        console.error('No Auth Headers Found')
        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }
    let idToken;
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer ')) {
        console.log('Found "Authorization" header');
        // Read the ID Token from the Authorization header.
        idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer')[1];
        console.log("fire token : "+idToken);
    }

    try {
        const decodedIdToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken);
        console.log('ID Token correctly decoded', decodedIdToken);
        req.user = decodedIdToken;
        next();
        return;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while verifying Firebase ID token:', error);
        res.status(403).send('Unauthorized');
        return;
    }
}
app.use(cookieParser);
app.use(validateFirebaseIdToken);
```

I have tried to use different firebase account also but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at onCall functions, auth verification is simpler https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Error was happening when splitting the JWT token

```
idToken = req.headers.authorization.split('Bearer ')[1]; -->needed a space
```